# Is it possible to add cs file references in LinqPad?

Tags: linqpad, linqpad7

I know I can add assemblies to LinqPad and I know I can paste in classes in queris, but is it possible to add CSharp class files(cs) and reference these in a query window?

I tried to a few classes but could not access them even if I included the namespace (in f4)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can include .cs files with the `#load` directive (LINQPad 6 and later):

```
#load "c:\source\MyLib\Utils\LinqExtensions.cs"
```

Relative paths and wildcards are also supported:

```
#load "..\..\source\myutil\*.cs"
#load "..\..\source\shared\*.cs /s"
```

Comment: Fantastic addition. It will help so much integrating LINQPad in larger development efforts. Any aspect of your code can be put on the testpad, executed against the plethora of data options available and explored.